# bnf/ebnf for xml schema

Tags: xsd, bnf, ebnf

I'm looking for a BNF/EBNF of XML Schema.
I just found the one for XML (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml or extracted at http://www.jelks.nu/XML/xmlebnf.html).

Well it's a starting point, but I'm curious that I couldn't find a more specific one for XML Schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess because nobody finds that useful, and it would be too complex. If somebody want to define an XML language, such as XML Schema, they would probably use XML primitives like elements or attributes (using XML Schema, Relax NG, DTD, etc.), not characters. One of the reasons XML was invented is to have a meta language for creating other languages.

Comment: Well, I think I'm ok with your answer.

Comment: XML isn't a meant to create other languages. It's a data-language (or a meta-language) with which you can write the syntax of other languages (like XHTML). You can't really define the syntax of XHTML with XML, or even the syntax of Pascal for that matter.

Answer (score -2):

I think the fiirst step would be to start with the xsd for [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd) and to use [Colibri](http://www.jcolibri.com/articles/bdd/xml/xsd_viewer/xsd_viewer.html#le_programme_delphi) to generate a bnf grammar.

I will check when i m back home. The Colibri's author say:

> Il s'agit là d'un premier jet que nous pourrions affiner.

But i definitevly think it got potential.

Comment: For everyone who can't read french (like me), here is the (google)translation: "This is a first draft that we could refine."