# In Context Free Grammar, how to define a pair of tags, like <abc>data</abc>?

Tags: context-free-grammar, bnf, ebnf

The expected language is like:

```
<hat>Nike</hat><car>Toyota</car>...
```

The difficulty I have is how to specify to ensure that within a pair of tags, the start tag and the end tag both have the same name.

The `tag` is the combination of [a-zA-Z] with length less than 10.

```
<tag>data</tag>
```

Comment: Don't use "regex" as a tag for "regular languages", if that is the goal :)

Comment: That looks entirely possible to me.  Assuming the set of allowable tags names is defined ahead of time.

Comment: @AlexBrown So what [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) accepts the above but rejects `<foo>data</bar>`? Does this extend to an *arbitrary* `<x>..</x>`?

Comment: <Anything> = <raw text no brackets> | <SomeTag>; SomeTag = <HATblock> | <Carblock> | <Fooblock> | <ABCBlock> | <FooBlock>; HATblock = <HATstart> <Anything> <HATend>; CarBlock = <CarStart> <Anything> <CarEnd>; <CarStart> = "<car>"; <CarEnd> = "</car>" ... etc.

Comment: @AlexBrown Yes, for a finite set of symbols. I *believe* the OP was looking for more ("arbitrary"), but I yield to that.

Comment: Yes, but when I said I would charge $200/h for stakeholder meetings to hammer out the requirements spec, he just said "answer the question".

Comment: Also, whoever said that the grammar had to be finite?

Comment: @AlexBrown In a CFG, V is a *finite* set of non-terminals and Z is a *finite* set of terminals ..

Comment: I'm pretty sure an *infinite* context free grammar would work, even for arbitrary tag names.

Comment: Is there such a thing as an "infinite context-free grammar"?  Isn't the whole point of a grammar that it contains a certain limited set of productions?

Comment: @cHao English grammar is definitely not context-free ..

Answer (score 1):

tldr; *Neither BNF nor EBNF can express this CFG in a reasonable manner.*

Consider using EBNF *and* explicitly - through EBNF comments, or outside context - either:

1. Impose a restrictive rule in the Pair production, or;
2. Introduce a way to represent a finite set of "template" non-terminals.

Depending upon usage, a poof that these changes/restrictions still produce a CFG may be required.

---

(This old prelude relates to a non-CFG, as the question was first written.)

To the best of my knowledge, `<x>..</x>` for an *arbitrary and unknown* `x` is not a CFL because a [Context Free Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) is restricted to a *finite set* of both terminals and non-terminals. Yet, by definition above, `x` is *not guaranteed* to be in that set.

However, given a *little leeway*, one can add informal restrictions to [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%2dNaur_Form) notation. Of course, these are *outside* of the EBNF syntax itself.

```
Pair = "<" Tag^1 ">" Content "</" Tag^2 ">"  (* Where Tag^1 equals Tag^2 *)
Tag = .. (* If a finite set, this could still be converted to
            formal EBNF by rewriting the above Pair as all possible alterations
            as shown in the next section.
            Only small values of "finite" are reasonable to express. *)
Content = ..
```

Specifications like [ECMAScript](http://es5.github.com/#A-toc) include a few such restrictions that *may* reside outside of a CFG and thus outside of EBNF.

However, if this language *is* a CFL then it can be represented by a CFG such as:

```
Pair = HatTagPair | CarTagPair | .. (* All possible non-terminal Pairs *)
HatTagPair = "<hat>" Content "</hat>"
CarTagPair = .. (* And so on.
                   While it's technically possible to have non-terminals
                   A, B .. AA, AB .. and so on, this quickly
                   becomes very impractical in EBNF. *)
```

Neither BNF nor EBNF have a "shorthand" way to formally represent such repetition and I would argue "tag is the combination of [a-zA-Z] with length less than 10" is not a *reasonable* finite set of terminals, although it *is* finite and thus within the realm of a CFG ..

There may be *other* [CFG metasyntax forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntax) that can be used to describe such a language formally, but not in plain BNF/EBNF.

Comment: thanks for answering, I just updated the question. In this case, it should be CFL.

Comment: The definition of a CFL is that there is such a CFG for it :) It just might be *very long* and verbose. See Alex Browns long comment for how such a BNF CFG might look.

Comment: got you. does any EBNF support this to make it looks simple?

Comment: @JackWM Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the EBNF for XML:   http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags which defines an element as beginning with STags and ending with ETags easily enough:

```
element ::= EmptyElemTag | STag content ETag
```

But as for keeping them the same, I think you'd need pretty far thinking look-aheads defined in the lexing strategy.  A related SO post [bnf/ebnf for xml schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578100/bnf-ebnf-for-xml-schema) suggests it may be better to drop the goal of a CFG and take a more basic approach in code.   All that said, I don't know how the many XML parsers out there actually go about it.

Comment: Or could it be that XML itself is not a CFL?

Comment: They typically don't.  at least not strictly with BNF etc.  Most XML parsers i've seen just see start tags, end tags, and text...and push and pop rather than trying to define it entirely within the grammar.